# Migrations and Tinker as Tools to Design and Finalize your Database before moving forward

Tags: laravel

I am working on a web application which has more than 30 tables and thought of designing the database first, using models and migrations. Then to test the relationships etc... through tinker. Is this a good way of doing this or is there any other better way. What i need is to finalize the DB Structure before moving in to creating views and controllers

Answer (score 0):

Just Create Migration for each table with their models and later.
You Can use Eloquent to Connect them all by Many to Many or Many to One Relationships.
Rest depend on you.